# Batch file explanation

Tags: batch-file, upload

Can someone please help me to understand a simple batch file? Supposedly, this batch file is supposed to pull information from an **MS Access** database named "Widgets" in preparation for upload to an off-site server. So I am double-clicking on the file on my PC, which pulls data from tables in a database that is physically located on a different PC (local server) in my office. Then it exports to an **excel file** which is uploaded to an off-site server. Here is the script:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\msaccess.exe" "C:\Backup\Widgets.mdb" /X Job_Search_Export_Macro
```

It doesn't seem to be working - after running it I can see the excel file that it creates. What I can't see is if the off-site server is grabbing the data. What am I doing wrong? I hope I have provided enough background information.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the batch file?

Comment: how can somebody tell you without the content of the file.

Answer (score 2):

All that batch file does is start MS Access and instruct Access to open the **Widgets.mdb*** database and run a macro called **Job_Search_Export_Macro** (`/X` is a command line switch for msaccess.exe that tells it to invoke the specified macro). The batch file doesn't actually do any of the other stuff you described. It's the macro that's purported to do that, and if it's not working, the problem lies in the macro's VBA code, not the batch file.

Since the question just asks to explain the batch file, I'm posting this as an answer. If you want to resolve the problem, you'll need to provide the macro's code, and add the `vba` and `ms-access` tags.